# Can I freeze silverlight SolidColorBrush?

Tags: c#, silverlight, system.windows.media

I have a silverlight application that I want to optimize!

Am i right to assume reducing the number of new objects of type `System.Window.Media.SolidColorBrush` may be an advantage? (i'm talking thousands...)

I'm looking to use only a couple of instances for , say 16 colors.

Furthermore I would like to freeze the brushes, but the option is not available! and I can't add the PresentationCore dll.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not:

check http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/11/Text-on-a-Path-in-Silverlight.html for further reading...

big let down in silverlight